# Firebase admin fetch cloud platform's usage information

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am making a software using firebase, this software has both user UI and Admin UI. An admin either activate, deactivate or remove certain users and do nothing. I want to add some more features to the admin UI. Something like being able to check my firebase account's usage, current plan and so on.
In simple words, is there any way to find below details of a single firebase project of mine using firebase-admin package?

1. Used storage bucket space and totally available bucket size, downloads and uploads
2. Firestore database write and read counts and maximum read/writes as per the current plan
3. The total number of users currently existing in my firebase auth
4. Cloud functions errors count

Being able to fetch these data in realtime would be more better and there maybe some kind of way for drawing graphs on the dashboard on the basis on these data.

I have initialized firebase-admin by calling `admin.initializeApp();` and the code for activating and or deactivating users. What about the analytics ? Is it possible with firebase-admin ? I'd tried a lot Googling but didn't found a way...

Comment: Cloud Storage buckets don't have a max size.  You can put exabytes of data in one - you will have a very hard time reaching any practical limit. You might want to read the documentation for the Firebase Admin SDK to find out what it can do.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase Admin SDKs currently don't provide any of the meta-information you are looking for. You can find the current list of functionality in the documentation.